# Nginx: 502 BAD GATEWAY while deploying django to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-config

I am trying to deploy a django website on aws EC2 instance with Nginx. I am getting the following error.

```
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: **.***.***.***, , server: **.**.***.*, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "*.amazonaws.com"
```

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder I have a file with the following configurations

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name your_public_ip;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/mySiteFolder;
}
location / {
    include proxy_params;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

}

Where is the mistake that I am committing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: how are you runnig the server and how you are accessing it?

Comment: By running `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: I am using gunicorn as wsgi server if that is what you asked.

Comment: i mean how you are running your django server? and as you have used proxy pass you need to keep the django server running or else nginx wont be able to connect

Comment: if you are using gunicorn this is not how you do it in nginx. you need to check it

Comment: Ok. If I should use the above settings then which server should I use?

Comment: you dont need any server for the above settings. use `nohup python manage.py runserver &` and the go to you public ip in browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186766/discussion-between-laxman-and-exprator).